# How to display users on current page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, passport.js

For example I have a page with url "/foo", and I need to display my authenticated users nicknames on this page. Is there any default node.js/passport function for this, or I need to add every user of this page to database and display it with websockets?

User schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: {type: String, required: true },
    nickname: { type: String, default: 'User'},
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Check if user is logged in:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    req.session.oldUrl = req.url;
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: You could add the user's nickname to the express' `req` when a user logs in, and then send it along with all subsequent responses.

Comment: @promisified, I know how to add only one, current user "req.user.username" but how to add another users on this page?

Comment: You could maybe use local array and send that with all subsequent responses? So basically every time a user logs in put the nickname in to the array, and send the array along. Just a thought.

Comment: Assuming you store your user sessions in MongoDB, could you post the schema of your sessions collection

Comment: @Dan Green-Leipciger done.

Comment: Could you post an actual session record from your database. You should have a collection called 'sessions' or something similar.

Comment: @Dan Green-Leipciger I haveonly my own collections, and nothig what liioks like "session" or so on...

Comment: Could you post a document from the users collection for a user who is currently logged in and another for a user who is not currently authenticated (with any sensitive info redacted). There should be an expiry time there that passport uses to check if a person is authenticated.

Comment: @Dan Green-Leipciger done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142766/discussion-between-dan-green-leipciger-and-bim-bam).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it in a service that hosts stories. I had to display the number of users and their names on the current story page. I wanted to keep the solution simple enough so I decided to use a simple table in SQL.

In an SQL table with a single column, I stored `PAGE_{PAGEID}_USER_{USERID}`.

For every page when fetched by the user I added an entry on this table and queried the table column with the regex `PAGE_{PAGEID}_USER_(.*)` with updatedAt less than 1 minute of the current time.

This gives you the IDs of the users on the current page in the past 1 minute.

PS: The correct way to do this would be to do this very same thing in a Wide Column Store